# EF Fluent API: Discriminator column is NULL for Derived Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am working on creating an Entity Framework (v6) Code First model from an existing database. After endless hours of frustration working with the EF Fluent API, I finally have a mapping which (almost) works as I want. Specifically, I have a conceptual model which is hierarchical, and I'm trying to map one particular entity which is split across three different tables. The POCO classes look like this:

```
// Base Class

public class Parameter
{
    // Primary Key for the 'Parameters' table
    public int Key { get; set; }

    ...
}

// Derived Class 1

public class EmbeddedMessageParameter : Parameter
{
    // Primary Key for the 'DataTypeEmbeddedMessage' table.
    public int DataTypeKey { get; set; }

    ...
}

// Derived Class 2:

public class EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter : EmbeddedMessageParameter
{
    // Primary Key for the 'DataTypeEmbeddedMessageCollection' table.
    public int CollectionDataTypeKey { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The database has the 'Parameters' table, the 'DataTypeEmbeddedMessage' table and the 'DataTypeEmbeddedMessageCollection' table. The 'Parameters' table contains all of the data for the `Parameter` parent class and contains a discriminator column called 'DataType'. If 'DataType' = 'Embedded Message', then an `EmbeddedMessageParameter` object is created. If 'DataType' = 'Embedded Message Collection', then an `EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter` object is created.

The Fluent API code in my DbContext class is as follows:

```
// Map the Parameters table.

modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>().ToTable("Parameters");
modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>().HasKey(param => param.Key);
modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>().Property(param => param.Key).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<Parameter>().Property(param => param.Key).HasColumnName("ParameterID");

// Embedded Message Parameters.

modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageParameter>()
   .Map(m =>
   {
      m.Properties(p => new
      {
         p.Key,

         ...
      });

      m.ToTable("Parameters").Requires("DataType").HasValue("Embedded Message");
   })
   .Map(m => m.ToTable("DataTypeEmbeddedMessage"));

modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageParameter>().HasKey(p => p.DataTypeKey);
modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageParameter>().Property(p => p.DataTypeKey).HasColumnName("AutoKey");
modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageParameter>().Property(p => p.DataTypeKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
...

// Embedded Message Collection Parameters.

modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter>()
   .Map(m =>
   {
      m.Requires("DataType").HasValue("Embedded Message Collection");
      m.ToTable("DataTypeEmbeddedMessageCollection");
   });

modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter>().HasKey(p => p.CollectionDataTypeKey);
modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter>().Property(p => p.CollectionDataTypeKey).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
modelBuilder.Entity<EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter>().Property(p => p.CollectionDataTypeKey).HasColumnName("AutoKey");
...
```

This mapping works well for the most part. I can read `EmbeddedMessageParameter` and `EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter` objects from the database and create and update them. However, there is one problem. If I create an `EmbeddedMessageParameter` object and save it to the database, the 'DataType' discriminator column in the 'Parameters' table is correctly populated with the value of 'Embedded Message'. However, when I create an `EmbeddedMessageCollectionParameter` object and save it to the database, the 'DataType' discriminator column is NULL. I am expecting it to have 'Embedded Message Collection' in this case.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?